# When trying to signup with paypal am getting this error

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

```
Uncaught exception 'PPConnectionException' with message 'error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES
```

Am getting this error when am trying to signup. It was worked last week . but now its not working help me friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do any of these following links help you:
['PPConnectionException' exception is thrown in PayPal adaptive Payment 'Pay' request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387235/ppconnectionexception-exception-is-thrown-in-paypal-adaptive-payment-pay-req)

[PayPal REST Api error: response 401 PPConnectionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023881/paypal-rest-api-error-response-401-ppconnectionexception)

Please give any information you can like what browser you are using and what OS

Comment: Browser chrome , OS ubuntu

Comment: Are you using a sandbox api?

Comment: Yes sandbox with rest api and seamless checkout